# Is it true that this mean inequality $ \bar{x}(m+1) \ge \bar{x}(m) $ is always correct if $m \in\mathbb Z$ and $x>0$?

Tags: inequality

Where $ \bar{x}(m) = \left ( \frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^m} \right ) ^\tfrac1m$.

I'm asking this because I've noticed that $$\bar{x}(2) \ge \bar{x}(1) \ge \bar{x}(0) \ge \bar{x}(-1).$$
Is it true that for all $m \in Z$ and $x>0$ $$ \bar{x}(m+1) \ge \bar{x}(m)? $$  I've gone through various wikipedia articles but haven't found this inequality shown, so I doubt it's correct.

Comment: $$\sqrt{({1 \over \sqrt{2}})^2+({1 \over \sqrt{2}})^2 \over 2} \ge {{1 \over \sqrt{2}} + {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \over 2}$$ is correct because RHS and LHS are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please pardon my earlier comment (which stemmed from missing the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor in your question.

It can be seen that for every $1\leq p<q$ (not necessarily integers) and all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ one has
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p\right)^{1/p} = \|x\|_p \leq n^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\|x\|_q = n^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q\right)^{1/q}$$
(one particular way of verifying this is using Lagrange multipliers.)

While I prefer this arrangement for highlighting the norm-equivalency, rearranging does give the required result.

Comment: I've actually found on the Internet that in general,
if $p < q$ and $p,q \in R$, then $M_p(x_1,\dots,x_n) \le M_q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $\bar{x}(a)=M_a(x_1,\dots,x_n)$,
and the two means are equal if and only if $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_n$.
It follows from the fact that, for all real $p$,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial p}M_p(x_1, \dots, x_n) \geq 0$
which can be proved using Jensen's inequality.